# At what point in the Fragment lifecycle is a RecyclerView ready?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragment-lifecycle

I populate the RecyclerView like this:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player, container, false)
    view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.songs).adapter = object: RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
            val item = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_song, parent, false)
            return MyViewHolder(item)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
            (holder.item as TextView).text = files[position].tag.title()
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int = files.size
    }
    return view
}
```

`item_song.xml` is just a `TextView`.

Now I want to make the currently playing song **Bold**:

```
        val songs = view?.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.songs)
        
        val song = songs?.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0)?.itemView as TextView
        // or val song = songs?.layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(0) as TextView
        song.setTypeface(song.typeface, Typeface.BOLD)
```

When I throw this code into the `OnClickListener` for some `Button`, it works. The item gets bold. However, I want this to happen before the view is presented to the user. But when I put this code in `onStart`, `onResume`, or even in `onViewCreated`, both

```
songs?.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0)
```

and

```
songs?.layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(0)
```

return `null`. *Always*. Thus it seems to me that the RecyclerView has not been populated yet with the items from `files`. So the question is, when exactly in the Fragment lifecycle does that happen? At what point is it safe to call above methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I want to make the currently playing song Bold:

Step #1: Have the model data reflect whether or not the song is current. In other words, whatever `files` is should hold this data.

Step #2: Have your `onBindViewHolder()` take this into account when updating the views of the row. For every `onBindViewHolder()` call, update the `TextView` to be normal or bold based on the model data.

Step #3: When the currently-playing song changes, update the model data to reflect the changes, and call `notifyItemChanged()` on the `RecyclerView.Adapter` to tell the adapter that the two positions (formerly-current and newly-current) need to be re-rendered.

> Now I want to make the currently playing song Bold:

That is not a good solution. Beyond the problems that you are currently seeing, it will not work with scrolling:

- Rows get recycled, and so now some random other song is bold as the user scrolls your list
- The same row does not get reused for the same position, so when your user scrolls back, your currently-playing song might not be bold anymore

> So the question is, when exactly in the Fragment lifecycle does that happen?

There is no relationship between the fragment lifecycle and when the `RecyclerView` sets up its views.